# Получить сумму значений массива

Tags: php

Есть такой массив:

> array ( '18-24' => array ( 0 => 'female/5', 1 => 'male/10', 2 => 'female/20', ), '25-34' => array ( 0 => 'female/50', 1 => 'male/30', 2 => 'female/10', )

Как на выходе получить массив вида:

> array ( '18-24' => array ( "female" => '25', "male" => '10'), '25-34' => array ( "female" => '60', "male" => '30' )

То есть чтобы суммировались значения мужчин и женщин.

Вот так вывожу свой текущий массив:

```
$demograph = array();
foreach ($arrDemo as $valueDemo) {
    $demograph[$valueDemo['vozrast']][] = $valueDemo['pol'].'/'.$valueDemo['col'];
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил код, теперь выдает без нотисов, и думаю такой вариант самый простой:

```
$arr = [
    '18-24' => ['female/5', 'male/10', 'female/20'],
    '25-34' => ['female/50', 'male/30', 'female/10']
];

$new = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $new[$key] = [];

    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        $dc = explode('/', $v);

        if (!isset($new[$key][$dc[0]]))
            $new[$key][$dc[0]] = 0;

        $new[$key][$dc[0]] += $dc[1];  
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
Array
(
    [18-24] => Array
        (
            [female] => 25
            [male] => 10
        )

    [25-34] => Array
        (
            [female] => 60
            [male] => 30
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку представленный вами массив вы таки генерируете и он не особо удобен для обработки, то вернемся к исходным данным (я несколько переименовал ключи):

```
$valueDemo = [
    [ 'age'=> '18-24', 'sex' => 'female', 'qnt' => 5],
    [ 'age'=> '18-24', 'sex' => 'male',   'qnt' => 10],
    [ 'age'=> '18-24', 'sex' => 'female', 'qnt' => 20],
    [ 'age'=> '25-34', 'sex' => 'female', 'qnt' => 50],
    [ 'age'=> '25-34', 'sex' => 'male',   'qnt' => 30],
    [ 'age'=> '25-34', 'sex' => 'female', 'qnt' => 10],
] ;
```

далее, следует получить уникальные значения `age` и использовать их как ключи результирующего массива:

```
$data = array_fill_keys(array_unique(array_column($valueDemo, 'age')), ['male' => 0, 'female' => 0]);
```

Начальными значениями будет пары `['male' => 0, 'female' => 0]`

И осталось пройти по исходному массиву и просуммировать данные:

```
array_walk($valueDemo, function($v) use (&$data){
    $data[ $v['age'] ][ $v['sex'] ] += $v['qnt'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так я бы решал проблему:

```
$demograph = [];
foreach ($arrDemo as $valueDemo) {
    $demograph[$valueDemo['vozrast']][$valueDemo['pol']] += $valueDemo['col'];
}
```

В итоге для каждой возрастной категории для каждого пола Вы будете суммировать количество людей того или иного пола.

На выходе будет что-то типа:

```
[
    '18-24' => ['male' => 10, 'female' => 25],
    '25-34' => ...
]
```

Comment: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting ')'**

Comment: Cкопируйте себе только эту строчку "$demograph[$valueDemo['vozrast']][$valueDemo['pol']] += $valueDemo['col'];"

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: 18-24 ` `Notice: Undefined index: pol in`